# How to delete column in all tables

Tags: firebird

I am use Firebird 2.5
I have multiple tables with column name 'col1', and I would like delete it.

I can use this statement:

```
DELETE FROM RDB$RELATION_FIELDS
WHERE RDB$FIELD_NAME = 'col1';
```

But I do not know is it safe.

I try to use execute block for multiple execute statements, but I do not know, how to combine it.

```
SET TERM ^ ;
EXECUTE BLOCK AS
    DECLARE s AS VARCHAR(200)
BEGIN

WHILE (SELECT rf.RDB$RELATION_NAME FROM RDB$RELATION_FIELDS rf WHERE rf.RDB$FIELD_NAME = 'AKTYWNY';) DO
BEGIN
     ALTER TABLE :s DROP c1;
END

END^
SET TERM ; ^
```

Comment: Messing with system tables is NOT safe, use `alter table drop column` instead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is example how to do this in stored procedure :

```
create or alter procedure DELETE_COL (
    F_COL char(31))
as
declare variable V_STAT varchar(256);
declare variable R_NAME char(31);
begin
  for
  select f.rdb$relation_name
  from rdb$relation_fields f
  join rdb$relations r on f.rdb$relation_name = r.rdb$relation_name
  and r.rdb$view_blr is null
  and (r.rdb$system_flag is null or r.rdb$system_flag = 0)
  where f.rdb$field_name = :f_col
  order by 1, f.rdb$field_position
  into
    :r_name  -- Table Name
  do
    begin
      v_stat = 'alter table ' || :r_name || ' drop ' || :f_col;
      execute statement(v_stat); /*because alter table ... is not allowed here */
    end
end
```

You can use this in `execute block` also.